# Generate JavaScript to make a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, drop-down-menu

First, I tried to make a Dropdownmenu directly in the CSS but it doesn't work like that, because I use ASP.NET and the html Code gets generated.
Here's my jsfiddle for my html code: https://jsfiddle.net/rxLg0bo4/2/ 

And this is how my menu works in ASP:

```
<nav id="menu">

            <asp:Panel ID="pnlMenu" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlSubmenu" runat="server">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </asp:Panel>
        </nav>
```

But now I know that I have to use a JavaScript, because I can't adress some of them, if you look at the jsfiddle you will get it.

 But I don't really know JavaScript, so I need some help.
This is a script, which I made:

```
  $('#pnlmenu').on('click', function click(){
        $('#pnlSubmenu').height(50);});
```

So in the end I would like to have it work like that: 
When you hover over menu1, the first submenupanel should dropdown with its submenulinks. 
Can anyone show me how to do that?

Comment: SO has so many questions like this.example :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19497434/how-to-create-dropdown-box-dynamically-using-javascript-in-jsp

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mouseover` and `mouseout` events of jquery to `fadeIn/fadeOut` the menu see this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rxLg0bo4/3/) to get you started, but you need to work out the other way so your submenu needs visibility toggled instead.

```
$( "#pnlMenu .menu_link" ).mouseover(function() {
    $(".submenu_panel").css("height", "100px");
    $("#pnlSubmenu").fadeIn( "slow" );
});

$( "#pnlMenu .menu_link" ).mouseout(function() {
    $(".submenu_panel").css("height", "0px");
    $("#pnlSubmenu").fadeOut( "slow" );
});
```

Comment: Can I use things like .menu_link in the javascript? And should't I also use .submenu_panel for fadeIn?

Comment: It is now working but how can I do it, that if i want to click something on the submenu, it shouldn't fade out

Comment: Did you only add the javascript, because if I take this function an delete the other two, it isn't happening anything.